# Can't understand the difference between username length in the state and in the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

How can I synchronize the regexp test validation with rendering, because it seems like for example if the validation regexp allows 5 characters, it will turn true when I have already 6 characters in the input field. It seems to me like it has something to do with rendering states.

**username state:**

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState({
    name: "",
    isValid: false,
  });
```

**handle username function:**

```
  function handleUsername(e) {
    const regexp = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,32}/gi);
    const isValid = regexp.test(username.name);
    setUsername(() => {
      return {
        name: e,
        isValid: isValid ? true : false,
      };
    });
    console.log("isValid - ",
      isValid,
      "|",
      "username.name.length - ",
      username.name.length); // => isValid -  false | username.name.length -  5
  }
```

**run console.log outside the function:**

```
console.log(
      "username.name.length - ",
      username.name.length); // => username.name.length -  6
```

I tried to figure out why this actually happen but it ends up with more confusions.

Comment: Why don't you use `isValid`? You always update `isValid: true`.

Comment: @kyun, my bad, I made the changes after posting the question actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState acts async, so you are console.logging the stale state.

```
  function handleUsername(e) {
    const regexp = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,32}/gi);
    const isValid = regexp.test(username.name);
    setUsername(() => {
      return {
        name: e,
        isValid: true,
      };
    });
    console.log("isValid - ",
      isValid,
      "|",
      "e.length - ",
      e.length); // => isValid -  false | e.length -  6
  }
```

Either use the variable that defines the new state, or console.log it in the useEffect with username dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(username.name.length)

}, [username])
```

Comment: I used the variable that defines the state, it works.